# Error response from daemon:TLS handshake timeout on docker

Tags: docker, docker-pull

I installed Docker on Windows Server 2019 using the following commands

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
Start-Service Docker
**To Running Linux containers on Windows Server 2019**
Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMSFTProvider
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "$null", "Machine")
Install-Module DockerProvider
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -RequiredVersion preview
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")
Restart-Service docker

I encountered this error when I tried to pull an image or log in to Docker Hub
**Error response from daemon:TLS handshake timeout**
I would appreciate it if someone could help me

I searched for this error and did not get a definite answer

Comment: can you provide the things you have tried and check? this could happen because of multiple reasons. Have you checked that the docker service is running? have you installed wsl2 or enabled virtualization? (docker will work with hypervisor if you not using wsl2)

Comment: @Nate1zn Hello, Yes, the Docker service is active and I have activated the virtualization. Thank you for your kindness. One of my friends answered that this problem occurred because of Iran's internet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your installation. Internet in Iran has been disrupted since 2 months ago and for many websites TLS handshake has been disrupted.

To fix this you need to use vpn or use shecan.ir as your dns.

Comment: Hello and thank you Mojtaba Ahadi